# Dynamic background color in Bootstrap Carousel with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a strange behaviorin Bootstrap Carousel which I am using with AngularJS. Below is the HTML code where I am trying to dynamically add background color to each thumbnail. What I observe is the following:

1. Initially, the "active" part of carousel adds background color dynamically to each thumbnail as expected.
2. However, once I start rotating the carousel, all thumbnails lose their background color.
3. Now, when I reload the page, all thumbnails get background color again.

So I cannot understand what causing the loss of background color initially during rotation? Thanks.

```
    <div class="well">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">


                <div ng-repeat="imgSet in imgSets" ng-class="{item: true, active : $first}"> 
                    <div ng-class="row">
                        <div ng-repeat="img in imgSet track by img.id" class="col-sm-3">

                            <a href="/appDetail/{{img.id}}" class="thumbnail" style="background-color: {{img.tile_color}};"> 


                                <img ng-src="{{uri}}/{{img.image}}" alt="Image" class="img-responsive" height="{{img.tile_height}}" width="{{img.tile_width}}">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    <!--/row-->
                </div>
                <!--/item-->

            </div>
            <!--/carousel-inner--> 

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
        </div>
        <!--/myCarousel-->
    </div>
    <!--/well-->
```

Comment: Here I tried to reproduce the issue in a more simpler example. It looks like we need to put single quotes for that to work http://plnkr.co/edit/KOjRnZNu1wQff76x8skF?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Well I found how to fix it, but I still do not understand why the original is not working (and why the fix is working):

my *{{img.tile_color}}* is a string of the form *"#1956B7"* (or any other #). I thought one must have *"#"* sign in front of the number. When I removed the *"#"* it started working.